# Null Point Reference on Android 12 but not on Android 9

Tags: java, android

I am writing a small Android app using Java. Now is there a strange problem that my app runs on Android 9 very well, but crashes on Android 12. My Logcat tells me, Java gets a null pointer Reference at a certain location. To me, this doesn't make any sense. If there was a null pointer reference in my Java code, why would the app work on Android 9 then?

You can find my app [here](https://github.com/turw41th/DnDHealthTracker/tree/develop).

The Error occurs in this [file](https://github.com/turw41th/DnDHealthTracker/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/ch/turwaith/ddhealthtracker/TrackerActivity.java) on line 104, which is the 3rd line of the following code block:

```
characterNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView_characterName);
String tempCharName = intent.getStringExtra("characterName");
characterNameTextView.setText(tempCharName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have 2 layout files for TrackerActivity. For Android 12 (v31) it is loading the second file.

[image: activity_tracker file tree]

The `NullPointerException` is caused as the `TextView` with id `textView_characterName` is not present in the `v31` layout file.

Either delete the second file or make sure ALL the **ids** and **views** are consistent across both the files.

Comment: Thank you @Gardener, I missed out on that. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Okay wow I would never have guessed that, thanks a lot! So it is perfectly safe to just delete the v31 file?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly safe to delete that file.

Comment: @Turwaith There are numerous diffs between the two however; so you'll need to investigate as to the "why" - particularly with the addition of `onClick`s in the v31.